# Import media in bulk with caption and titles?

Tags: media, bulk-import, csv

I am converting a non-WP site to a new WP site. The old site has about 500 images that I need to import to the media library in bulk, and I need it to include the captions and titles.

Is there an import method that will allow me to import the images with their caption and title fields intact? I'm not sure yet what kind of DB export I'll be able to get from the old site, but I'm hoping there is something I can use to map it to the WP media fields.

Comment: If you purely need a ready-made plugin please note that asking for plugin recommendations is considered not in scope here.

Comment: @Rarst, edited. I'm looking for any method, either an existing wordpress import method, a function I can use or a ready-made plugin.

Answer (score 0):

As WordPress doesn't show the files you upload into the Upload directory in the Media folder, you can use this plugin http://wordpress.org/plugins/add-from-server/.
You can mange it from the Dashboard.

Comment: I've used this plugin, but I don't think it imports text into the caption and description fields. I could use this to upload the images, but I need to figure out how to map an import file from the old site to these media fields so I can populate them with caption and description text in bulk.